# Overriding Written text in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a gray-scale grid and used command below to print text on it which prints text in black.

```
text (cPixel+25, rPixel+25, 'X', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'middle', 'FontSize', 38);
```

now, I want to remove this text, i am trying to do so by changing the text color to white using 'Color' property shown below but it prints in black.

```
text (cPixel+25, rPixel+25, 'X', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'middle', 'FontSize', 38, 'Color', [1 1 1]);
```

If you please tell me that which property to use to make gray-scale color white. i used 'color' property with RGB value [1 1 1] it also prints text in black, and also tried with 'color' property with 1 as a gray-scale value, but, it gives me error that you should use [R G B] color value.

My Question is how to set gray-scale text color on a gray-scale grid using text() function in matlab. What i tried is briefed above. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me. But maybe your problem is, that you are not really changing the color of the existing text object but instead create a new object on top of the old one.

To actually delete the old object, you need to keep the handle and then delete it:

```
textHandle = text(cPixel+25, rPixel+25, 'X', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'middle', 'FontSize', 38);
delete(textHandle)
```

and if you actually want to change the color, you can also use the handle to do that:

```
set(textHandle,'Color',[0 0.5 1])
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: You solution is good [sietschie](http://stackoverflow.com/users/977098/sietschie), but, I did it other way. I do not have the reputation to vote it.